# MediaController not working

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

My VideoView works but my MediaController doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I'm doing the positions wrong or probably not...

Here's my code:

```js
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    VideoView resultvideo;
    MediaController mediacontroller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_URI");
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(uri);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mediacontroller = new MediaController(Main2Activity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);

        mediacontroller.show();
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(resultvideo);

        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
        resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        resultvideo.start();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*MediaController* should be set with *VideoView* in order to work.You should have called the below:

```
resultVideo.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
```

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: Put that before resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);